# Visualising trees from random forest using graphviz with feature and class names

Tags: python, dataframe, scikit-learn, random-forest, pygraphviz

I have trained a randomforest classifier with randomsearch CV and would like to export say the first 5 decision trees using graphviz. My features data is in dataframe format and my classes data is in series format.

I am able to export the trees using the code below

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

#define classifier
clf = RandomForestClassifier()

#define the pipeline - chain the column transformer and the classifier
pipe = Pipeline([('ct',column_trans), ('clf',clf)])

#randomised search cv with hyper parameters
#input the parameters for search space
param_grid = {
    'clf__n_estimators':[500, 1000, 5000],
    'clf__max_features':['sqrt','log2'],
    'clf__max_depth': [5, 10, 15, 20],
    'clf__min_samples_split': [2,5,10,15],
    'clf__min_samples_leaf': [2,5,10,15],
    'clf__bootstrap': [True, False],
    'clf__criterion': ['gini','entropy']
}

#create the random forest classifier object

rscv_rf = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = pipe, param_distributions=param_grid, scoring= 'f1_macro', verbose=1, random_state=42)


#fit the rf model with X-train and y_train data

rf_model = rscv_rf.fit(X_train, y_train)

#plot decision trees
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 1,ncols = 5,figsize = (5,5), dpi=800)

for index in range(0, 5):
    tree.plot_tree(rscv_rf.best_estimator_.named_steps['clf'].estimators_[index],filled = True, ax = axes[index])
axes[index].set_title('Estimator: ' + str(index), fontsize = 11)
fig.savefig('rf_5trees.png')
```

However, when I try to include the Feature Names and the Class Names using the code below, I get index error issues. Is there something I am missing out? I'm guessing that each tree will show different features and my original dataframe only has 25 features while the column transformer in my pipeline actually does one hot encoding to create 155 features, appreciate any form of help. Thank you.

```
#plot decision trees
fn= list(X.columns)
cn= [str(s) for s in y.unique()]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 1,ncols = 5,figsize = (5,5), dpi=800)
for index in range(0, 5):
    tree.plot_tree(rscv_rf.best_estimator_.named_steps['clf'].estimators_[index], feature_names = fn, class_names = cn, filled = True,ax = axes[index])
axes[index].set_title('Estimator: ' + str(index), fontsize = 11)
fig.savefig('rf_5trees.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get a working solution but happy to receive other solutions as well

```
#retrieve the numerical and categorical variables before pipe and put into lists
numerical_columns = X.columns[X.dtypes == 'int64'].tolist()
categorical_columns = X.columns[X.dtypes != 'int64'].tolist()

#get the features that were one-hot encoded
onehot_columns = rscv_rf.best_estimator_.named_steps['ct'].named_transformers_['onehotencoder'].get_feature_names(input_features=categorical_columns)

#create a list of all the feature columns
feature_columns = = numerical_columns + list(onehot_columns)

fn = feature_columns
cn= [str(s) for s in y.unique()]

#plot the chart and save the figure
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 1,ncols = 5,figsize = (5,5), dpi=800)
for index in range(0, 5):
    tree.plot_tree(rscv_rf.best_estimator_.named_steps['clf'].estimators_[index], feature_names = fn, class_names = cn, filled = True,ax = axes[index])
axes[index].set_title('Estimator: ' + str(index), fontsize = 11)
fig.savefig('rf_5trees.png')
```